# React Native localhost SSL certificate is Invalid

Tags: node.js, react-native, ssl, expo

I've started this React Native project using Expo a few weeks ago, and everything was going fine until yesterday.

When I ran `expo start`, I got the Metro Bundler as usual, and I click "Run in web browser", as usual, the VS Code terminal prompted me with a password input for a localhost certificate thing. I have no idea what it was, but there was [this link](https://github.com/davewasmer/devcert#why-am-i-seeing-a-password-prompt-on-windows) to some local SSL signing tool, that I also don't know anything about. Even with the link I wasn't sure what password I was supposed to type in, so I just pressed enter without typing anything and that's where I'm at now.

I can't run my app in the browser anymore. Whenever I try to do so, I get this:

[image: halp]

And the log only has this:

> PS D:\Projects\GroceryApp\GroceryApp.Web> expo start
>
> Starting project at D:\Projects\GroceryApp\GroceryApp.Web
>
> Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19003
>
> Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
>
> Ensuring auto SSL certificate is created (you might need to re-run with sudo)
>
> Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
>
> debug Watch mode is not supported in this environment
>
> debug Checking for a newer version of React Native
>
> debug Current version: 0.61.4
>
> debug No release cache found
>
> debug No release cache found
>
> debug Checking for newer releases on GitHub
>
> debug No release cache found
>
> debug Saving "6d6386b01438c6ef0acd213d304b5839" to cache
>
> debug No release cache found
>
> debug No release cache found
>
> debug Latest release: 0.60.0
>
> Tunnel ready.
>
> exp://192.168.0.108:19000
>
> QRCODE
>
> To run the app with live reloading, choose one of:
>
> • Sign in as @redacted in Expo client on Android or iOS. Your projects will automatically appear in the "Projects" tab.
>
> • Scan the QR code above with the Expo app (Android) or the Camera app (iOS).
>
> • Press a for Android emulator, or w to run on web.
>
> • Press e to send a link to your phone with email.
>
> Expo  Press ? to show a list of all available commands.
>
> Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.

So, I tried forcing it by pressing `W`, and then I get this:

> Attempting to open the project in a web browser...
>
> (node:15116) **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The certificate "D:\Projects\GroceryApp\GroceryApp.Web.expo\web\development\ssl\cert-localhost.pem" is invalid.**
>
> error:2007E073:BIO routines:BIO_new_mem_buf:null parameter
>       at validateKeyAndCerts (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\src\addons\withDevServer.ts:26:11)
>       at getHttpsConfig (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\src\addons\withDevServer.ts:62:5)
>       at createDevServer (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\src\addons\withDevServer.ts:191:12)
>       at Object.withDevServer (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\src\addons\withDevServer.ts:101:31)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\src\webpack.config.ts:419:21)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\webpack\webpack.config.js:8:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\webpack\webpack.config.js:4:12)
>       at Object.default_1 [as default] (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\webpack\webpack.config.js:87:12)
>       at C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\src\index.ts:21:71
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\webpack\index.js:8:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\webpack\index.js:4:12)
>       at createWebpackConfigAsync (C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\webpack\index.js:26:12)
>
> (node:15116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)
>
> (node:15116) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Which makes sense, because that file is completely empty.

Sorry for long post, I wanted to make sure all the logs were here.

Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also haven't been prompted with the password entry anymore, and I'm pretty sure I was supposed to have entried my windows password, but I can't figure out how to changed that.

Comment: I just started using Expo, but I'm experiencing the same symptoms. I got the thing to work exactly once, after a passel of "accept this CA cert?" messages. Then I started getting those errors. I note that the cacert-local.pem file is 0 bytes.

Comment: Same here. Empty locahost certificate file, and if you delete it, it just generates back up, empty again. I kinda lost hope on getting it to work with https on localhost (especially after the astonishing lack of answers both here and on the oficial forum(https://forums.expo.io/t/react-native-localhost-ssl-certificate-is-invalid/36380/7). If it helps you you can run it without SSL with `expo start --no-https`. That's what I've been using.

Comment: Oh, man, thank you. That will help me get started. I'm hoping they'll fix it before I get too far down the rabbit hole. (And that this doesn't prevent me from doing the next thing, which is trying to do logins with amplify.) I have a feeling somebody upgraded something somewhere and the disconnect cascades out.

Comment: There is a new version of expo (3.19.2), and it is slightly better. I get an error: "› Failed to self-sign SSL certificates for HTTPS. Falling back to insecure https. You can re run with `--no-https` to disable HTTPS, or delete the `.expo` folder and try again." Deleting .expo doesn't help, but if I accept its bogus certificate I think it works.

Comment: Yeah, updating to the newer versions sort of fixed it. Now my browser is complaining about the "unsafe" certificate, but at least i get to use my https local domain. Deleting .expo, unfortunately, didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you start an expo app with the option `--https` it will create a certificate which initially is not trusted, and on my Mac, that certificate lives here:

```
/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert
```

This certificate is used to generate the `.pem` files used by the expo server for TLS (which live here: `.expo/tls`).  Deleting the `.pem` files is useless because expo will just regenerate them from the dev cert it created the first time you tried to serve the app with TLS/https. Hence, the solution is to add the dev cert to the list of trusted roots, which can be done (on osx) with:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -p ssl -p basic '/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert'
```

Maybe someone can chime in with a similar solution for Windows and/or Linix.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to upgrade to a newer version of expo and to re-run again.